# Which C compiler produces the smallest native Windows executables?

Tags: compiler-construction, executable

Lately I've been working with the Windows API, trying to write gui-based Windows programs that are as small as possible. Speed isn't really much of an issue for me, what I'm going for is the size of the executable.

Just wondering which C compiler will produce the smallest binaries, especially without any tricks or messing with it too much.

Comment: This is impossible to answer without actually *building your program*. Every program will be different. Try some compilers and find out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have much experience with this on Windows, but [Tiny C Compiler](http://bellard.org/tcc/) does produce some very small executables.

I tested it on a basic "Hello world" program, and the size of the exe was 1.5KB, about 1/12 the size of the MinGW executable. I didn't test it with Visual C++ (because I don't have it), but you get the idea. It makes small executables.

Answer (score 1):

Look up executable compression (e.g. [UPX](http://upx.sourceforge.net/)). That will get you a lot farther than any compiler, at the cost of occasional false positives from virus scanners.

Comment: Yeah, I've been using UPX. I was wondering weather or not I could further reduce the size of the executable by switching to another compiler. I'm using Visual Studio, by the way.

Comment: The thing about compression is that with a good algo (and UPX's is supposed to be pretty darn good), you're limited more by the actual information you're conveying rather than the input. At a certain point you just can't cram n bits of information into n-1 bits.